# RocksDb Java API support for Transactions

Tags: rocksdb, rocksdb-java

Does RocksJavaAPI have the support for transactions? I see that there is a Transaction DB class present in the JAR. I am not able to do a begin transaction on transaction Db class.

```
RocksDB db = TransactionDB.open(options, "/Users/jagannathan/Desktop/My Files/db/rocksdb")
```

I am not able to do db.beginTransaction as such methods are not available. Any pointers on how to accomplish in Java are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different open method. You currently use the open method of the base class ([RocksDB](https://javadoc.io/static/org.rocksdb/rocksdbjni/6.20.3/org/rocksdb/RocksDB.html)).

Use either:

```
public static TransactionDB open(Options options,
                 TransactionDBOptions transactionDbOptions,
                 java.lang.String path)
```

or

```
public static TransactionDB open(DBOptions dbOptions,
                 TransactionDBOptions transactionDbOptions,
                 java.lang.String path,
                 java.util.List<ColumnFamilyDescriptor> columnFamilyDescriptors,
                 java.util.List<ColumnFamilyHandle> columnFamilyHandles)
```

To get a [TransactionDB](https://javadoc.io/static/org.rocksdb/rocksdbjni/6.20.3/org/rocksdb/TransactionDB.html) object. This object you can then use to call `#beginTransaction`, which will return an [Transaction](https://javadoc.io/static/org.rocksdb/rocksdbjni/6.20.3/org/rocksdb/Transaction.html) object. This transaction can then be used similar to a RocksDB, where you can put, delete etc. and commit if you're done.